# $rootScope Watch is not seeing google api loading

Tags: angularjs, authentication, google-plus

So I am trying to figure out the easiest route for authentication with AngularJS and Google Plus. I have worked with angular-google-plus and it is great, spits back all my user information. I Then wanted to get back if a user is registered or not when they come to a new page or controller in my project. So I found [this post](https://github.com/mrzmyr/angular-google-plus/issues/26) which basically said the project needs to extend the api. Fine, but he implements a watcher that, when executed in my Controller works for the gapi, but when it checks for the gapi.auth it returns undefined. My console.log tells me both of them are there and are objects. Here is my controller code:

```
.controller('LoginController', ['$scope', '$state', '$window', '$http','$rootScope', 'GooglePlus', function ($scope, $state, $window, $http, $rootScope, GooglePlus) {
    var checkGoogleReady = $rootScope.$watch(function() {
        console.log(gapi);

    $scope.login = function() {
        GooglePlus.login().then(function (authResult) {
            console.log(authResult);

            GooglePlus.getUser().then(function (user) {
                console.log(user);
            });
        }, function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    };
}])
```

So the stuff inside the login() function all works, returns everything I need. But outside it, it fails to get gapi.auth and never changes after that. I feel like it checks, finds gapi, then changes gapi.auth and then tries to wait for another change, never getting the gapi.auth. Here is a picture of the console:

[image: Console after the page loads, no buttons clicked]

So you can see all 3 objects actually have the auth property on them. So I am not sure why the gapi.auth is coming back undefined.

Comment: I am not going to dissect what I say. The guy's code was good - it was trying to solve the problem that both of us had. You are correct - it is not good in that it was not working, in MY implementation of it. Which is why I posted here, to see if I was doing something wrong or not writing code in the right way to make the gapi recognized. Rather than focus on my word of "good" - please help solve the problem at hand. In addition, I did try to solve the problem with the code that was in the post. You do not see all of the testing I did in the console to narrow down the issue.

Comment: Further, I do understand the code written. It is using a watch to check for when gapi and gapi.auth are both objects. What I am posting about, is specifically how this code is working with the watch interactions of angularjs. It appears to me as though it is hitting a change, possibly changing both objects, and then starting the watch again. Because gapi.auth is undefined. Or maybe calling gapi.auth is incorrect, but my image seems to suggest gapi.auth is correct. This is specifically what I was asking.

Comment: Ok, I checked on this more, the angular-google-plus component is loading in gapi immediately in the run command of a provider. But for some reason, the elements on gapi are being seen by angular controller as undefined until a button is clicked. So I am not sure if the run command is not loading in that element right away, but it sees gapi and not gapi.auth. What is weird, is in the console, I can call gapi.auth, with no errors. It gets loaded right away - weird part is angular doesn't see it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138963/discussion-between-tcoulson-and-georgeawg).

Comment: This was not plagiarized. I was simply trying to give a perspective of code to demonstrate why the overall component was not getting gapi.auth. But if you insist, I have removed the code that is offending.

Comment: the problem isn't even with my code or angular's code. It has to do with gapi and the asynchronous way of loading. I added a timeout - it works after the 1 second timeout. What is weird is I tried it with a recursive function and it didn't work. Wondering now what the best way of loading gapi ahead of the controller in angularjs?